# Updating an double everytime a Object is added to a ArrayList

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, double, updates

In my game I want all the zombies to have a random color. I have already figured out how to change the color of the zombies but the problem is that I wan't all of them to have different colors but right now one color is applied to muliple zombies and the it takes some time before the next color is applied to the next zombies. The code below is the one I use for the moment for adding zombies.

```
    public void initZombie(){ 
     for(int i = 0; i < player.getZombies(); i++){
      int thaXSize = xSize + 800;
      randomXSpawn = Math.random() * thaXSize + xSize;
      randomYSpawn = Math.random() * ySize;
      zombies.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
      randR = Math.random() * 255;
      randG = Math.random() * 255;
      randB = Math.random() * 255;
     }
for(int i = 0; i < zombies.size(); i++){
            Zombie z = (Zombie) zombies.get(i);
            int j, k, red, green, blue, alpha;
            for(j = 0; j < 64; j++){
                for(k = 0; k < 64; k++){
                    Color c = new Color(z.getBrImage().getRGB(j, k));
                    red = c.getRed();
                    green = c.getGreen();
                    blue = c.getBlue();
                    alpha = c.getAlpha();
                    int rgb = new Color((int) randR, (int) randG, (int) randB, alpha).getRGB();
                    if(red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 178){
                        z.getBrImage().setRGB(j, k, rgb);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the `randR`, `randG` and `randB` variables to update everytime one zombie is added so that non of them will have the same color, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you really need to add `0`?

Comment: As a side issue, if the program is non-trivial I think it is better to avoid use of Math.random(), other than possibly to get a default seed for a java.util.Random. If you use Math.random(), every run is different, which can get in the way of debug and performance measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we try adding the RGB colors to zombie class itself, so that every time a new zombie is created it has its own colors. This can be done by the constructor, something like this:

```
class Zombie{

    int randR;
    int randG;
    int randB;

    double randomXSpawn;
    double randomYSpawn;

    public Zombie(double randomXSpawn, double randomYSpawn) {
        super();
        this.randomXSpawn = randomXSpawn;
        this.randomYSpawn = randomYSpawn;

        randR = (int)Math.random() * 255;
        randG = (int)Math.random() * 255;
        randB = (int)Math.random() * 255;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell, what you're doing, but this

```
zombies.add(new Zombie(randomXSpawn,randomYSpawn));
randR = Math.random() * 255 + 0;
randG = Math.random() * 255 + 0;
randB = Math.random() * 255 + 0;
```

doesn't look like the random color components are properties of the new zombie that has been added the line before.

An idea would be adding a `Color rgb` parameter to the zombie constructor and set the color when you really create it.

Comment: Maybe it also needs `(int)` cast for each rgb value.